# How is XP divided when some party members are already level 99?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

Suppose three of my party members are already level 99, but one isn't yet. When I get XP, does it all go to the one who isn't level 99, or is it split four ways and wasted on the other three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it, and it appears that the XP is split four ways, and wasted on anyone who is already at max level.